# Querying a database in android

Tags: android

I have a table login2 in /data/data/sankalp.jain.shre/databases/loginfinal.db.

The database has been created correctly which i have verified myself using adb sqlite3 and querying the table.
Inserting from commandline works but using rawQuery,it seems data is not getting added(cant get it on commandline too).

```
   private SankalpDB dbhandle;   //SankalpDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
   private SQLiteDatabase sqdb;
   ..............

     public void open() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Opening");  //This also gets printed.
    sqdb = dbhandle.getWritableDatabase();
}



    public void addUser()
{   System.out.println("Adduser");
    System.out.println(sqdb.getPath());   ///prints /data/data/sankalp.jain.shre/databases/loginfinal.db

    sqdb.rawQuery("Insert into login2 values('ax13','Kate','password');", null);
    sqdb.rawQuery("Insert into login2 values('cax56','Natalie','passswd');", null);
 ....
 ...
sqdb.close();
}
```

The logcat output is not giving any error either.What am I doing wrong here.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and do the following:

```
Cursor c =  sqdb.rawQuery("Insert into login2 values('ax13','Kate','password');", null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  c.close();
```

Comment: Cursor c=sqdb.rawQuery("Insert into login2 values('ader','Kate','voldemort');", null);   c.moveToFirst();   System.out.println(c.getCount());//prints 0  c.close();
 }

Comment: run the whole query with movetofirst and close() and check the db

Comment: you can also try and use `sqldb.execSQL("Insert into login2 values('ader','Kate','voldemort')");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with the extended form

```
sqdb.rawQuery("Insert into login2 (alias,user,password)  values('ax13','Kate','password');", null);
```

where alias, user and password are the DB fields